# How to use multiple pipe filters in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I need to filter list of object by some criterias: `status, activity,position, category.`

I have decioded to create separated pipes: `StatusPipe, ActivityPipe, PositionPipe, CategoryPipe.`

I confused if I use it: `data | statusPipe | activityPipe | positionPipe | categoryPipe.`

At first I dont need apply all pipes, only those who selected in filter. Also I dont know where to store intermediate selected filter values, it can be primitive type like: `status:1` or complecated: `position: {x: 1, y :6}`.

I try to use oop principles and I agree that all filter should realize of principle of one responsibility, anyway it should be pipe class or my custom class.

Which approach to apply in my case for ability farther adding new filters?

My idea is to create a custom realization:

```
class FilterStatus implements Filter {}

class FilterPosition implements Filter {}

class FilterCategory implements Filter {}

interface Filter {
   apply();
}
```

Then create a concrete instance of filter and put it to one global pipe filter.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arrayForFilter: any, filter: Filter): string {

    return filter.apply(arrayForFilter);
  }
}
```

But what if I have some active filters?

```
transform(arrayForFilter: any, filter: Filter[]): string {
}
```

Another way is inject all available filter realization in pipe:

```
 @Pipe({
        name: 'filter'
    })
    export class FormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(private filterStatus: FilterStatus, private filterCategory: FilterCategory, private filterPosition: FilterPosition)
      transform(arrayForFilter: any): string {

      }
    }
```

In this case I dont know how to know whci filter is filled and active and how to apply some filter for icoming array of data?

Comment: before trying to do this, recommend reading angular's explanation for why they did not include a filter pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe ... it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not follow that way to apply multiple pipes if it's based on a filter selection.

First, create a general Pipe that can receive any kind of data in the values.
Then, that Pipe adds a second parameter, this is going to receive which filter to apply.
Inside your pipe, do a `switch` and add the cases for which filter is selected like:

```
switch(filter) { case 'status': ... break; case 'category': break; }
```

In this way, you don't have complex filters and pipes. You just receive which data to filter and in which way.

Now, when you change the filter, do a `ngModelChange` to your select so with a variable you can use it to pass that value through the Pipe as said.

Even if you have complex or really simple filters like `status:1` you can do whatever you want in this way and easier.

Comment: I want to use polymorphism instead switch

Comment: Well if you want to complicate yourself that's okay. But that is another path that is not going to work with pipes. You can't "filter" in that way. If you want to use like 10 pipes in the same for filtering then, inside your code you need to check for example "if have status then is this filter, if not, then, ignores this" and repeat on every pipe with the logic, and that is pretty bad ...so it's your choice, easy way, or the hard way with so much code that is useless.

Comment: I try to use strategy pattern for each kind of filter then wrap this into one global class filter that has method: `filter() { return filtersInstances.filter((f) => f.apply(array))}` then I call this method in pipe

Comment: Could you share an sample, I dont undrstand how to apply some filters at the same time for array of objects.